# How to prevent autoscroll to focused input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On some tap or click, I need to focus an input which is out of the viewport, but is animating in. However because of how browsers instantly scroll focused elements into view, my transition is screwed up.

So the simple question is, how to prevent autoscroll of focused input/textarea elements?

Here's an example of the unwanted behavior:

http://jsbin.com/nejiwoy/edit?html,output

```html
<div
 style="
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
 ">
 <div
  style="
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   height: 200px;
   background: green;
  ">
  <input 
   style="
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    border: none;
   ">
 </div>
</div>

<button onclick="document.body.querySelector('input').focus()">focus</button>
```

Comment: Do you want to disable scrolling inside the input ?

Comment: Why not focus after the animation has completed?

Comment: @DavidA because ios safari doesn't support `.focus()` on other thatn click handlers. [Here's some context.](https://medium.com/@brunn/autofocus-in-ios-safari-458215514a5f)

Comment: @ShahilM there is no scrolling inside the input. The inner div is the one being scrolled. I want to prevent that.

Comment: Hmm, good point about `.focus()`... would animating using `transform: ...` work for you?

Comment: @DavidA that's exactly what i'm animating : (

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an interrim fix for this - have tested and it works in latest Chrome. Use

`element.focus({ preventScroll: true })`

See the WHATWG [thread](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/834) on GitHub.

Comment: Noice! I hope I remember this next time I need it.